# Search and replace using reg ex in Dremweaver

Tags: regex, dreamweaver

i want to replace some parts in a file by dreamweaver using the search and replace function with reg ex.
How I can I specify this part:

```
<lastmod>2011-01-13T14:57:31+00:00</lastmod>
```

Is there any way to make this:

```
redirect301 http://www.mypage.com/this/that/
```

to

```
redirect301 hhttp://www.mypage.com/this/that/ http://www.mypage.com/this/that/lang/en/
```

Many Thanks in advance,
Cindy

Comment: Sorry, I don't quite get the question. What do you mean by that lastmod part at the beginning?

Comment: @ Adrian: i want to replace this part with nothing...

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you would want to search for `<lastmod>([^<]*)</lastmod>` to get the full `lastmod` tag.

As far as I understand regexes, this selector means "everything that is not the character `<`", so it assumes there will be no tags nested inside the `lastmod`. The parentheses are optional, but they allow you to refer to the matched string when replacing, like in the next case. Replace

```
redirect301 http://www.mypage.com/([\S]*)/
```

with

```
redirect301 http://www.mypage.com/$1/ http://www.mypage.com/$1/lang/en/
```

to pass the mathching `this/that` to the `$1` variable. The regex matches all non-whitespace characters. I'm not sure how to account for missing trailing slashes, so watch out for inconsistencies. Hope it helps.